# how to get 4 cards in the same row currently i am having 2 cards in a row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am making a recipe web application but i am not using any inbuilt card feature from material ui or bootstrap. i want to have 4 recipe components in a row instead of two. Also the recipe component has a button named ingredient so whenever i click that button it should display ingredients only for that food recipe but instead it displays recipe for all the recipe components in that row. pls tell me how to fix this.
I am attaching the github repo link to the project :- https://github.com/ankita413/recipe
the ingredient component is defined in ingredient.jsx and its css in recipe.css
and recipe component is in recipe.jsx and its css in recipe.css
Also for the button functionality i am attaching the code right here and the image as well[when i click the ingredient button of first recipe the 2nd ingredient button also opens up but displays nothing i want that only the ingredient button which i click should open up][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4DUY.png
code for recipe component containing ingredient button

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import  './styles/recipe.css';
import Recipeingredient from './ingredient';
const Recipe = ({title,calories,image,ingredients}) => {
const [show,setShow] = useState(false);


return(
<div className="recipe">
    <h2>Search Recipe</h2>
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p>Calories: {Math.floor(calories)}</p>
    <img src={image} alt = {title}  ></img>
    <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>Ingredients</button>
   {show && <Recipeingredient ingredients = {ingredients}/>}
</div>
 
);


}
export default Recipe;
```

Comment: the code you've shown doesn't explain why you even get "2 in a row" - perhaps you are setting a `width` on the `recipe` - if so, reduce the width by half to get double the items per row

Comment: I would also suggest, create a sample in CodesandBox and share the link here, Also you have mentioned 2 different problem statement in single question. Please share the code for the first problem as here.

Answer (score 0):

in recipe.css

```
    width: 30rem;
    margin: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    padding: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 2rem 3rem 5rem #aaa;
  }
```

in app.css

```
.recipes{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here you have given a width of 30 rem which approx to 30*16px(since rem is not set to custom) for each card. Which is pretty much bigger for three cards it equals 1440 px and plus the margin of 3 rem which gives an extra 96px for each side for each card 1728px. So there is no way to get 4 cards in a row. That is you have made  `flex: wrap` for recipes. which simply move to the next line

so to fix this reduce the margin between each cards and also reduce the width of the card to something 300px. and margin to 1 rem.

for the 2nd question
I have created codesandbox for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-glade-pn58b
Actually, the 2nd recipe is not opened. But due to default auto height, the 2nd card is expanding.
for this, you can either define
`height:fit-content`

```
.recipe {
  width: 30rem;
  margin: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content; //add this
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 2rem 3rem 5rem #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Faiz Hameed It really helped and also understood why this happened.